# Conditionally importing css file in tailwindcss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Currently I'm importing a static css theme for syntax highlighting like:

```
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css'
```

Since I'm using tailwindcss and nextjs, instead of a static import wanted to import the highlight.js css file conditionally based on dark mode.

Basically I need a tailwindcss version of below code:

```
if(darkmode)
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark.css'
else
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css'
```

I tried the below plugin code, to no avail

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function ({  matchVariant, addBase }) {
      matchVariant('dark', (v) => {

        addBase(
         [
          `@import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark.css';`
        ]);
      })
    }),
  ]
```

Seems like I'm missing something basic as I thought conditionally importing a CSS file would have been an option in tailwindcss ?

Comment: did you find solution?, i need to do this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for myself. By generating styles based on highlight.js and compatible with tailwindcss and its dark theme.

Blogged about it here https://octocat.dev/posts/conditionally-styling-code-sections